# How to prevent autocomplete from overriding my keybindings?

Tags: key-bindings, auto-complete-mode

I've changed the keybinding `C-s` to save buffer, but when I'm writing code and `autocomplete` is visible, it rebinds this key to search for a pattern:

[image: Hitting C-S when autocomplete is open]

If I try to use `C-h k` to find out which function is bound to `C-s`, even with the `autocomplete` open, emacs tells me it's save buffer.

How can I find out what is overwriting the `C-s` keybinding, and how to avoid it?

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 on RHEL Linux, the active modes are Python Flymake AC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use auto-complete. But looking in (an old version of ) the source code I see this:

```el
(defvar ac-completing-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
     ...
     (define-key map "\C-s" 'ac-isearch)
  ....
```

So you probably just need to do something like this:

```el
(define-key ac-completing-map "\C-s" nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map SOME-OTHER-KEY 'ac-isearch)
```

I'd also suggest that you send a bug report to the auto-complete maintainer, asking for an easy way to discover the keys during completion.